# App closing on executing button click - Server Connection with my local XAMPP Server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, apache

I have been quite a lot through PHP and MySQL. Now I am focusing on creating an android app for the web app created and set up using PHP server in XAMPP. My problem is initially the app force closed due to some run-time errors that is caused by my code mistake. But now the problem is app closes without any force close notice. And also the database is not updated with the data I entered through the app.

addEntry.java:

```
package localhost80.sample1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.String;

public class addEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText Eed, Elno, Epar, Epcs, Emts, Ewt, Ect, Egw, Efw, Erem;
public Spinner Evar;
public String str_ed, str_lno, str_par, str_pcs, str_mts, str_wt, str_ct, str_var, str_gw, str_fw, str_rem, str_var_code;
public Button Add, Clr;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_entry);
    addInput();
}

private void addInput() {
    Eed = findViewById(R.id.ed);
    Elno = findViewById(R.id.lno);
    Epar = findViewById(R.id.par);
    Epcs = findViewById(R.id.pcs);
    Emts = findViewById(R.id.mts);
    Ewt = findViewById(R.id.wt);
    Ect = findViewById(R.id.ct);
    Egw = findViewById(R.id.gw);
    Efw = findViewById(R.id.fw);
    Erem = findViewById(R.id.rem);
    Evar = findViewById(R.id.var);
    Add = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    Clr = findViewById(R.id.btnClr);

    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            str_ed = (Eed.getText()).toString();
            str_lno = (Elno.getText()).toString();
            str_par = (Epar.getText()).toString();
            str_pcs = (Epcs.getText()).toString();
            str_mts = (Emts.getText()).toString();
            str_wt = (Ewt.getText()).toString();
            str_ct = (Ect.getText()).toString();
            str_gw = (Egw.getText()).toString();
            str_fw = (Efw.getText()).toString();
            str_rem = (Erem.getText()).toString();
            str_var = (Evar.getSelectedItem()).toString();

            switch (Evar.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    str_var_code = "fw";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    str_var_code = "brw";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    str_var_code = "mw";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    str_var_code = "bw";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    str_var_code = "ow";
                    break;
            }
            displayToast(str_ed, str_lno, str_par, str_pcs, str_mts, str_wt, str_ct, str_var, str_gw, str_fw, str_rem);
            serverLinking hostlink = new serverLinking(addEntry.this);
            hostlink.execute(str_ed,str_lno,str_par,str_pcs,str_mts,str_wt,str_ct,str_var_code,str_gw,str_fw,str_rem,"POST");
            finish();
         }
    });
    Clr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Eed.setText("");
            Elno.setText("");
            Epar.setText("");
            Epcs.setText("");
            Emts.setText("");
            Ewt.setText("");
            Ect.setText("");
            Egw.setText("");
            Efw.setText("");
            Erem.setText("");
            Evar.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
}

private void displayToast(String d_ed, String d_lno, String d_par, String d_pcs, String d_mts, String d_wt, String d_ct, String d_var, String d_gw, String d_fw, String d_rem) {
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    String toasttext;
    toasttext = "Entry date : " + d_ed + "\nLot no : " + d_lno + "\nParty : " + d_par + "\nTotal Pcs : " + d_pcs + "\nTotal mtrs : " + d_mts + "\nTotal Weight : " + d_wt + "\nCount : " + d_ct + "\nVariety : " + d_var + "\nGray Width : " + d_gw + "\nFinishing Width : " + d_fw + "\nRemarks : " + d_rem;
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START, 0, 0);
    Toast.makeText(addEntry.this, toasttext, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

serverLinking.java:

```
    package localhost80.sample1;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;

    public class serverLinking extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
private String link;
private Context context;
private String ed,lno,par,pcs,mts,wt,ct,var,gw,fw,remarks,method;

public serverLinking(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
{
        method = arg0[11];
        link = "http://192.168.0.104/narmadaa_trial1/android/add.php";
        if(method.equals("POST"))
        {
            ed = arg0[0];
            lno = arg0[1];
            par = arg0[2];
            pcs = arg0[3];
            mts = arg0[4];
            wt = arg0[5];
            ct = arg0[6];
            var = arg0[7];
            gw = arg0[8];
            fw = arg0[9];
            remarks = arg0[10];
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("ed","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("lno","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("par","UTF-8")+"="+
                        URLEncoder.encode("pcs","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("mts","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("wt","UTF-8")+"="+
                        URLEncoder.encode("ct","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("var","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("gw","UTF-8")+"="+
                        URLEncoder.encode("fw","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("remarks","UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();

                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "Data Added Successfully";
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
    }
```

Still I have no idea on what has gone wrong in my code. The database is neither updated on execution. I have omitted the PHP part in this section as far as my knowledge there is nothing wrong with the PHP file.

Please anyone do help me. I am stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You put the finish() method directly after the start of the async task so, because the async-task actually start a new thread, your app call the finish() method while the serverLinking is still working. Now, i don't know if android automatically menage this problem anyway, in order to solve THIS problem,you can try to put the finish() in the onPostExecute() like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
    Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGH_LONG).show();
    ((Activity)context).finish();
}
```

and removing it from where it is now. I don't know if it's going to work but it's not a bad habbit anyway

Comment: Thanks for your help I figured out and tried with showing the exception details in toast and found out that the error was due to failing socket connection.

The main cause was failing to include permissions in manifest. So I included
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
This solved my issue of connection.
But another problem arised now. The connection has become stable and I am able to add data to the database but all fields I have used in the PHP file are entered as blank or 0.

Comment: O, nice, happy for you ! You should post this second thing in another question.

Comment: Thanks Silvio for your help